# Without using packages, define function \lastMonth as Last month, The year for last month LaTeX

Tags: macros, date

Using this format, how would I assign the month to be last month/year instead of current month/year? For example, if I run it tomorrow (01/01), \lastMonth =January, 2022, but I will need it to be \lastMonth =December, 2021.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lastMonth}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
December\fi, \number \year} 

\begin{document}
\lastMonth
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...!? Seriously, why not use packages?

Comment: By checking if month is January, then decrement the year, then do a similar switch-case based on the month...? Looks like you already know enough commands to do it yourself...

Comment: This is a coworkers code, I'm completely new to latex @user202729 and I can't use packages for reasons unknown to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Just shift the month names down and subtract 1 from the year in January

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lastMonth}{\ifcase \month\or %
December\or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or
October\or November\fi, \number \numexpr\year\ifnum\month=1 -1\fi\relax} 

\begin{document}
\lastMonth

\def\month{1}
\lastMonth
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this mean that you have to specifically define month{1} everytime it's January or was that a line you added to illustrate what would happen if it's January?

Comment: @ColeMG no I just forced it to `1` to save waiting until tomorrow to test it:-)